# Pass different parameters separately in React-Router

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router

Hi I am using react router with switch statement. I am passing two variables to a page and pass parameters city and name.

Use cases:

1. city and name both are passed (working fine)
2. only city is passed
3. only name is passed

   ```js
   <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/search/:city" component={Search} />      // only the route defined first works
    <Route exact path="/search/:name" component={Search} />      // doesn't work
    <Route path="/search/:city/:name" component={Search} />      // Working fine
   </Switch>
   ```

In the case of passing only city or only name I am not able to use both at the same time. Only one route works which ever is defined first.

How can I use both of these at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

you can write your code this way:

```
<Route  exact path="/search/city/:city" component={Search} />
<Route  exact path="/search/name/:name" component={Search} />
```